# How to properly analyze a non-inferiority study

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, non-inferiority

In my study I try to show that treatment A is not inferior to treatment B. With a delta margin of tolerance =-2. I had discussed the subject in a previous post, of which here is the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/602185/how-to-calculate-p-value-for-non-inferiority-study-with-r). For two-sided statistical tests I have this difference $\mu_A−\mu_B= -0,7$ $[-2,1; 0.8]$.
But in one-sided test I have $-0.7$ $[-1.9; +\infty)$.

If I conclude from the two-sided test, $H_0$ is not rejected. Non-inferiority is therefore not proven.

On the other hand, with respect to the one-sided test, non-inferiority is proven.

Which is more valid of the two analyses? Or do they interpret each other differently?  Or does the decision to use a one- or two-sided test depend on the objectives set beforehand, whether or not superiority is to be tested in the case of non-inferiority? I still don't understand in an operational way the unilateral or bilateral test.

Comment: You seem to be using commas and period interchangeably. And can you clarify if the encircled amount is the 95% CI e.g.? If it is, how is the CI derived? By inverting the hypothesis test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both tests are valid, but they address different questions.

Two-sided tests are used to answer questions like:

- Is there *any* relationship between outcome and treatment? (existence)
- Treatment has no influence on the outcome *whatsoever* (nonexistence)
- Treatment has *no relationship* with the outcome (also nonexistence)
- The outcome in A is *not any different* than the outcome in B (nonexistence again)

One-sided tests come from directional questions:

- Is A better than B?
- Is doing X worse than doing Y?
- Is A better than B by at least k?

You should use the CI (or a p-value) that corresponds to the hypothesis you designed your experiment to test. If your goal was to show non-noninferiority, that means using the second CI/p-value.

Comment: This answer does not (*yet*) address the specific **noninferiority** form of the one-sided test, which also entails a threshold $\delta$.

Comment: @Alexis Isn't that a special case of "Is A better than B by at least k"?

Comment: @Dang it! Yes... I missed that. Carry on! :D <3

Answer (score 3):

Your significance levels (or confidence levels for the CIs) are not the same. You used 5% for the two-sided test and also 5% for the one-sided test. So that people don't game "the system" in such a "silly" way, it is usual (at least when we talk about a drug regulatory setting) that one-sided non-inferiority testing is done at half the significance level of two-sided testing. In that case, there's no inconsistency.

Comment: In unilateral I should use 0.025 as a threshold. Is that right?

Comment: With the test with a threshold of 0.025, I have indeed the same lower bound for the confidence interval [-2,1; +Inf], and the the p.value=0.03 which is consistent with the confidence interval. None of them are significant, since the p.value must be less than 0.025 to be significant. Is it correct ?

Comment: I don't think this is actually the case. Both one-sided and two-sided CIs offer the same coverage rate of $1-\alpha$, and using a smaller $\alpha$ is overly conservative, wasting experimentation bandwidth. I do agree with you on avoiding gaming and pre-specifying the number of sides to be congruent with the question the test is meant to address.

Comment: I agree with dimitriy. Avoiding gaming should be done through [pre-registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preregistration_(science)), which includes not just the hypotheses intended to be tested, but also the chosen level $\alpha$. Using a lower $\alpha$ than $0.05$ is fine if that was the intention of the author all along, but this too is part of the pre-registration process.

Comment: With NI, the water is a bit muddled. But if you wanted to demonstrate that a new drug is better than a placebo (seems to suggest a one-sided null hypothesis), but others suggest you should have equipoise and do two-sided testing, you could argue for either approach. In that setting, it makes no real sense that you should now have to provide less evidence, just because you say you are not interested in whether your drug is worse than placebo. That's certainly the logic you get for doing NI testing at the 2.5% level e.g. from regulatory guidance by FDA https://www.fda.gov/media/78504/download.